# restructure object to 2D array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to restructure a pain object to a 2D array object.

Originally, I have something like:

```
{ 
   "education_histories.0.school":[ 
      "The education_histories.0.school field is required."
   ],
   "education_histories.0.degree":[ 
      "The education_histories.0.degree field is required."
   ],
   "education_histories.1.school":[ 
      "The education_histories.1.school field is required."
   ],
   "education_histories.1.degree":[ 
      "The education_histories.1.degree field is required."
   ],
}
```

I would like to restructure it to be like:

```
[ 
   { 
      "school":[ 
         "The education_histories.0.school field is required."
      ],
      "degree":[ 
         "The education_histories.0.degree field is required."
      ]
   },
   { 
      "school":[ 
         "The education_histories.1.school field is required."
      ],
      "degree":[ 
         "The education_histories.1.degree field is required."
      ]
   }
]
```

Currently, I've been trying to do something like:

```
let validationErrors = []    

$.each(this.errors, (key, value) => {
  let splitKey = key.split('.')

  validationErrors[splitKey[1]] = { [splitKey[2]]: value }
})
```

Of course, this won't work because It keeps overriding until the last round. The output would be like:

```
    [ 
       {
          "degree":[ 
             "The education_histories.0.degree field is required."
          ]
       },
       {
          "degree":[ 
             "The education_histories.1.degree field is required."
          ]
       }
    ]
```

I wish I could do something like

```
let validationErrors = []    

$.each(this.errors, (key, value) => {
  let splitKey = key.split('.')

  validationErrors[splitKey[1]][splitKey[2]] = value
})
```

But this won't work either. It says `"TypeError: Cannot set property 'school' of undefined"`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to change much. If the object doesn't exist, create it, otherwise just set its property.  You can also use object destructuring and there's no need for jQuery:

```
  let validationErrors = []    

 for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.errors)) {
    let [ , index, name] = key.split('.');

    if(!validationErrors[index]) valudationErrors[index] = {};
    validationErrors[index][name] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try my way, I think it is not best solution:

```
const input = {
  "education_histories.0.school": [
    "The education_histories.0.school field is required."
  ],
  "education_histories.0.degree": [
    "The education_histories.0.degree field is required."
  ],
  "education_histories.1.school": [
    "The education_histories.1.school field is required."
  ],
  "education_histories.1.degree": [
    "The education_histories.1.degree field is required."
  ],
};

const raw = Object
  .keys(input) // ["education_histories.0.school", "education_histories.0.degree"]
  .reduce((pre, curr) => {
    const splittedStr = curr.split('.');
    const dataKey = splittedStr.pop(); // school
    const key = splittedStr.join('.'); // education_histories.0
    if (!pre[key]) {
      pre[key] = {};
    }
    pre[key][dataKey] = input[curr];
    return pre;
  }, {});

console.log(raw);

// {
//   "education_histories.0": {
//     "school": [
//       "The education_histories.0.school field is required."
//     ],
//       "degree": [
//         "The education_histories.0.degree field is required."
//       ]
//   },
//   "education_histories.1": {
//     "school": [
//       "The education_histories.1.school field is required."
//     ],
//       "degree": [
//         "The education_histories.1.degree field is required."
//       ]
//   }
// }

const output = Object.keys(raw).map((key) => raw[key]);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) are good for doing this sort of thing.

Suggested solution here, overly verbose explanation below.

```js
const input = {
  "education_histories.0.school": [
    "The education_histories.0.school field is required."
  ],
  "education_histories.0.degree": [
    "The education_histories.0.degree field is required."
  ],
  "education_histories.1.school": [
    "The education_histories.1.school field is required."
  ],
  "education_histories.1.degree": [
    "The education_histories.1.degree field is required."
  ],
}

// iterate over each key/value in the input object
// to build up the output.
const result = Object.entries(input).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {

  // split the key into parts
  // e.g. ['educaton_histories', '0', 'school']
  const [section, index, field] = key.split('.');

  // use the index to bin the message in the right slot
  // e.g. result.0 = { ... }
  acc[index] = {

    // keep anything that already exists in this bin
    ...(acc[index] || {}),

    // add the message under the field's name
    // e.g. school: [ ... ]
    [field]: value
  }

  // return the updated object
  return acc;
}, {})

// the object's values are in the format you're after.
// we don't need the keys (the indices)
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

`Object.entries(input)` returns an array of field/value pairs. So:

```js
const input = {
  'education_histories.0.school': 'school 0',
  'education_histories.0.degree': 'degree 0',
  'education_histories.1.school': 'school 1',
  'education_histories.1.degree': 'degree 1',
};

Object.entries(input);
```

Returns this array of arrays:

```js
[
  ["education_histories.0.school", "school 0"],
  ["education_histories.0.degree", "degree 0"],
  ["education_histories.1.school", "school 1"],
  ["education_histories.1.degree", "degree 1"],
]
```

Invoking `reduce` on this array calls your callback function for each item in the array, passing in the previous iteration result, and the current array entry:

```js
// reduce takes two args: a callback function and an initial value
Object.entries(input).reduce(callback, {})

// the callback function takes:
// 1) the result from the previous iteration, and
// 2) and the current array item:
function callback(result, currentItem) {
  // on the first iteration:
  // previousResult = {}
  // currentItem[0] === "education_histories.0.school"
  // currentItem[1] === "school 0"

  // incorporate the item into the result:

  // break the key on '.', and capture the three entries:
  // section === 'eduction_histories'
  // index === 0
  // field === 'school 0'
  const [section, index, field] = currentItem[0].split('.');

  // result.0
  result[index] = {
    // if result.0 already exists, keep what's there
    ...(result[index] || {}),

    // add the current item
    // school: 'school 0'
    [field]: currentItem[1]
  }

  // return the updated result.
  // this will be passed in for the next iteration,
  // and will be the final return value when reduce exits
  return result;
}
```

The callback can be inlined, giving you the example above.

```js
Object.entries(input).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  // ...
}
```